# Problem with Sproutcore

Tags: 12.04

I am trying to create an application using Sproutcore by doing the following:

```
cd /home/user/Development/Sproutcore
```

Then

```
sproutcore gen statechart_app TestApp
```

When I run the above command I see the following:

```
~ Created directory at apps/test_app
WARN 19:39:59.009 ~ For specific help on how to use this generator, type: sc-gen statechart_app --help 
FATAL 19:39:59.009 ~ Permission denied - /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sproutcore-1.9.1/lib/apps/test_app
```

Then I run the previous command again but this time with `sudo`.

```
~ Created directory at apps/test_app
~ Created file at apps/test_app/Buildfile
~ Created directory at apps/test_app/resources
~ Created file at apps/test_app/resources/main_page.js
~ Created file at apps/test_app/resources/loading.rhtml
~ Created file at apps/test_app/resources/_theme.css
~ Created file at apps/test_app/theme.js
~ Created file at apps/test_app/main.js
~ Created file at apps/test_app/statechart.js
~ Created directory at apps/test_app/states
~ Created file at apps/test_app/states/ready_state.js
~ Created file at apps/test_app/core.js

Your application target is now ready to use!
```

Although it says that my application is now ready to use I don't see any TestApp inside the Sproutcore folder.

Why is that? Am I missing something? I'm running 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

The line `FATAL 19:39:59.009 ~ Permission denied` indicates the directory wasn't created, probably because it didn't have permission.

So run the command with sudo

```
sudo sproutcore gen statechart_app TestApp
```

Comment: That's what I did and it works (no FATAL errors) but the problem now is that although it says that my application is created there is no application inside the sproutcore folder.

Comment: @KalPetros I saw the fatal error and recommended a fix based on that. As I'm unfamiliar with Spoutcore I cannot comment beyond that, good luck.